# Database splitting techniques

Tags: database, split

I am doing a research on ways to split data in a single database, to keep certain data separated but still in one place. For example: I have a store database. I want to split the database into 2 sections, physical store and online store. I know there are certain ways to achieve this other than making just two separate tables of course (which I don't want), but I am not familiar with them but I am sure there are people here that know these type of techniques. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're going to need something to separate them whatever happens. Be it via a table or a column.

Comment: I think what you need is database partition. A lot of modern database system has this function.

Comment: stackoverflow is not for opinions, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new table say "StoreType", give it the columns "Id" and "Name", then inside your "Store" table, have a new column "StoreTypeId".

You can then populate the "StoreType" with "Physical Store" and "Online Store", then just user the ID when populating the store.

If you use normalization for your database design, this is the sort of layout you'd get